# pagination for a custom query

Tags: custom-post-types, pagination, query

I am trying to create a query for a custom post type that will display as a list and I need to include numerical pagination to split the list up. For some reason none of the pagination solutions I have found work ; they add the buttons, but all those buttons do is refresh the page. Here is my code for my query. Oh, and yes I know that WP_query is thought to be better than get_posts, I just don't know if that well. If someone wants to convert my query from get_post to WP_query be my guest. And yes I know other posts talk about this but I haven't been able to get any of them to work.

```
    <?php $thismfg == the_title;
          $posts = get_posts(array(
        'posts_per_page'=> 30,
        'post_type' => 'crosses',
            'meta_key'  => 'original_manufacturer',
        'meta_value'    => $thismfg
        )); if( $posts ): ?>
            <?php foreach( $posts as $post ): setup_postdata( $post ) ?>
            <div style="width:33.3%;border:solid black 1px;padding:2px 10px;box-sizing:border-box;float:left;">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <div style="float:left;width:130px;"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
                <div style="float:left;width:20px;">/</div>
                <div style="float:left;width:130px;"><?php the_field('redirect'); ?></div>
            </a>
            </div>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: This line looks weird: `<?php $thismfg == the_title;`.

Comment: What's wrong with it? The code looks at the title of the page, then lists all "crosses" with an "original manufacturer" equal to the title. What's wrong with that?

Comment: [`the_title()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) is a WordPress function that echos the title, so the missing parenthesis for one. get_the_title() would a better choice here.

Comment: Alright, but that still doesn't answer the pagination issue.